# CONCAT ON Query in join more two table mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want concat the file image. 
Berfore that, this is my records;

**tb_barang;**

```
+-----------+-----------+------+
| ID_BARANG | VESSEL    | VOY  |
+-----------+-----------+------+
|         1 | TMS_GLORY | 0000 |
|         2 | TMS_GLORY | 0000 |
+-----------+-----------+------+
```

**tb_damage_per_coil;**

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| ID_DAMAGE | ID_BARANG | KETERANGAN |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|        35 |         1 | DAMAGE 1   |
|        36 |         2 | DAMAGE 2   |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**tb_file_image**

```
+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID_IMAGE | ID_DAMAGE | FILE_PATH                                                                                          |
+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       35 |        35 | D:/XAMPP/htdocs/develop_tsurumaru/assets/iwwi_file/DO_FOLDER/Damage_Report/0510-31-07-2016/35.jpg  |
|       36 |        35 | D:/XAMPP/htdocs/develop_tsurumaru/assets/iwwi_file/DO_FOLDER/Damage_Report/0510-31-07-2016/351.jpg |
|       37 |        36 | D:/XAMPP/htdocs/develop_tsurumaru/assets/iwwi_file/DO_FOLDER/Damage_Report/0520-31-07-2016/36.jpg  |
|       38 |        36 | D:/XAMPP/htdocs/develop_tsurumaru/assets/iwwi_file/DO_FOLDER/Damage_Report/0520-31-07-2016/361.jpg |
+----------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoAKE.jpg
```

My goal is, I want to concat the path of file into one record.
My query like this;

```
SELECT a.ID_BARANG, b.ID_DAMAGE, a.VESSEL, a.VOY, b.KETERANGAN
FROM tb_barang a
INNER JOIN tb_damage_per_coil b
ON a.ID_BARANG = b.ID_BARANG

WHERE a.VESSEL LIKE "%TMS%" AND a.VOY LIKE "%000%"

+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+------------+
| ID_BARANG | ID_DAMAGE | VESSEL    | VOY  | KETERANGAN |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+------------+
|         1 |        35 | TMS_GLORY | 0000 | DAMAGE 1   |
|         2 |        36 | TMS_GLORY | 0000 | DAMAGE 2   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need like this

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+------------+---------------+
| ID_BARANG | ID_DAMAGE | VESSEL    | VOY  | KETERANGAN | FILE_PATH     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+------------+---------------+
|         1 |        35 | TMS_GLORY | 0000 | DAMAGE 1   | FILE1, FILE 2 |
|         2 |        36 | TMS_GLORY | 0000 | DAMAGE 2   | FILE1, FILE 2 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+------+------------+---------------+
```

What should I use in my query ?

Comment: This question seems related to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686470/get-directory-on-a-file-that-path-has-stored-into-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select 
    tb_barang.ID_BARANG,tb_damage_per_coil.ID_DAMAGE,tb_barang.VESSEL,
    tb_barang.VOY, tb_damage_per_coil.KETERANGAN,
    GROUP_CONCAT('',tb_file_image.FILE_PATH) AS FILE_PATH
from tb_barang
left join tb_damage_per_coil on tb_damage_per_coil.ID_BARANG = tb_barang.ID_BARANG
left join tb_file_image ON tb_file_image.ID_DAMAGE = tb_damage_per_coil.ID_DAMAGE
group by tb_file_image.ID_DAMAGE
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47203/7) is here.