# Get directory on a file that path has stored into database

Tags: php

I have a path of file that I stored into a table database like this :

```
D:/XAMPP/htdocs/develop_tsurumaru/assets/iwwi_file/DO_FOLDER/Damage_Report/0080//thumbs/thumb_52.jpg
```

You know, this path is a string type now.
How to get its directory, which is :

```
D:/XAMPP/htdocs/develop_tsurumaru/assets/iwwi_file/DO_FOLDER/Damage_Report/0080//thumbs/
```

Thanks

Comment: Explain your requirements clearly. What did you meant by `get its directory`? Do you want to get the directory list under that `thumbs` folder?

Comment: This question seems related to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682984/concat-on-query-in-join-more-two-table-mysql-table)

Comment: Yup, I need list under thumbs folder

Comment: in that case, Check my answer @FadlyDzil

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of all the files and folders under `thumbs` folder, then follow the below code.

```
<?php
  $dir    = 'D:/XAMPP/htdocs/develop_tsurumaru/assets/iwwi_file/DO_FOLDER/Damage_Report/0080//thumbs';
  $files = scandir($dir);

  print_r($files); // This will print an array with all the files and folders
?>
```